# Why does an IP address request result in an HTML document in the browser?

Tags: html, python-3.x

```py
import requests

ip = requests.get("https://ifconfig.io/ip").content
print(ip)
```

if i run this code the output is `b'1.1.1.1\n'`
but if i press f12 on the actual page i can see there's an html code.
so what's happening exactly? why i don't recive the html stuff like `<head>`, `<body>` and other thing, and why it's in byte?
i also tried to download the page (just pressing ctrl+s) and i downloaded a `.txt` file with only written `1.1.1.1`

[image: image of html]

Comment: response content is always in byte , you need to use `response.text` for string. I only see my ip too and no html page if I visit the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is a side-effect of the web browser's dev tools. When examining a web page using dev tools, the browser shows its "fixed up" DOM instead of the raw HTML returned by the server. This may include closing HTML tags which were not properly closed, or in your case, the browser creates and injects its own HTML template for styling the `text/plain` HTTP response. Printing the `document.body` from the console shows the styling applied:

```
<body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[IP]
</pre></body>
```

Whereas right-clicking the page and selecting "View Source" shows just the IP address.

Don't rely on the `Elements` tab in the dev tools if you want to see the literal response from the server. Instead you can go to "Sources" and select the page, `Network > Response` for the correct HTTP request, `View Source`, or use `curl` (although there's no guarantee that the server won't change the response based off the user-agent).

Answer (score 1):

The element inspector in your browser shows a represention of the document that the browser has built to *show you the contents of the text file*.

It does not show you the page source.

If you load an HTML document it wouldn't show you the page source either, it would show you a representation of the document after error recovery, normalisation and JavaScript had been applied.

See `view-source:https://ifconfig.io/ip` for the actual source code of the page.